# uv4l configuration file missing

Tags: apt, uv4l

I ran "sudo apt-get install uv4l-uvc" and no errors were reported. The service status reported that the configuration file was missing. I found that /etc/uv4l was empty. However, "dpkg -L uv4l-uvc" reports that /etc/uv4l/uv4l-uvc.conf should have been included during installation. What could cause the configuration file to be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what went wrong. I ran "sudo apt-get remove uv4l-uvc" to remove the package. I noticed that the configuration file was still present so I removed it manually using "sudo rm -rf /etc/uv4l". When I tried installing uv4l-uvc again, the file was missing. From another post, I see that I should have used "sudo apt-get purge uv4l-uvc" to properly remove the configuration file.